# Login screen changed to old input style

Tags: greeter

Today in the evening I booted up my laptop and my login screen has changed to the following (taken from my N9)

[image: my laptop]

The login screen has changed to some old looking thing?

I can still login to my laptop and `dpkg -l | grep greeter` says

```
ii  lightdm-gtk-greeter                                         1.8.5-1ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1                                    amd64        simple display manager (GTK+ greeter)
ii  pantheon-greeter                                            2.0.2-0~r370+pkg43~ubuntu0.3.1                                  amd64        Pantheon Login Screen
```

Answer (score 1):

The package **lightdm-gtk-greeter** some how got installed. Purging it and reinstalling **pantheon-greeter** fixed it.

### To do it run the following commands in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm-gtk-greeter
sudo apt-get install pantheon-greeter --reinstall
```

Comment: I also having this issue ... but when doing the purge for the gtk greeter got this restult ... Package 'lightdm-gtk-greeter' is not installed, so not removed

Comment: trying the pantheon-greeter reinstall to see if that fixes the issue

Comment: forgot to mention ..i Am running Juno 5.0 ... and this does not work for me